# After adding one css class to div in Code Behind existing class disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one div `runat="server"`

```
<div class="MyFirstCssClass" id="DivID" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
<input>text</input>
</div>
```

in Code Behind I adding one attribute

```
DivID.Attributes.Add("class", "SecondCssClass");
```

after that in browser in div its only `SecondCssClass`

Comment: _after that in browser in div its only SecondCssClass_. I didn't get.

Comment: You need to get all of the class attributes and re-add them along with that other add

Comment: or modify existing: DivID.Attributes["class"] += " SecondCssClass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate the existing class with the new one

```
DivID.Attributes.Add("class", DivID.Attributes["class"] + " SecondCssClass");
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a space in between the 2 CSS classes?